# cannot import google places api Python

Tags: python, google-places-api

I installes this package : https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places

with the following steps:

```
pip install https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/zipball/master

OR

pip install python-google-places

Download source and then: python setup.py install
```

But when I try to imprt it, it says that there is no module named googleplaces, even if I can lockate the library in my library directory ( C:\Python\Lib\site-packages )

I tried adding it to the Python Path variable, but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Being new to python,I just had the same problem. If you're using anaconda and VScode like I am, a solution could be to be pay attention to the environment you're using and the environnement in which you installed the package.

Use `conda env list` to see which environment is active

Did you install the package in that environnement ? Did you launch VSCode from that environnement as well ? (sg in my case)

I solved the problem by launching VScode from the right env.

[image]

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Package Name is `python-google-places`

Try this to install the package:  `pip install python-google-places`

Comment: Did you notice the `pip install python-google-places` *in the question*?